# Unable to start SQL Server Browser service in Sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

we are unable to start the SQL browser service on one of our machine with below error:

[image: error]

I believe this to be the reason, why we could not connect to the instance with below error:

[image]

I tried troubleshooting as mentioned [here](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/46400/sql-server-browser-service-started-and-then-stopped/), by changing value in registry from 1 to 0, but still no luck.

SQLservices are also running.

Please help on how to resolve this!

@Mark- screenshot after running commands provided:

[image: screen]

[image: link]

Comment: Have you check out your 'Port Number'

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan, yes 1433

Comment: @KASQLDBAHave you try to check through command prompt 'net start sqlbrowser'. Is your browser services has started succesfully or not.

Comment: When the browser service is running, you can access the instance without a specifying the port. you can successfully login with the following connection parameters (IP + InstanceName).

Comment: ,If the browser service is not running and the customized static port is also missing in the connection parameters. To login successfully you have to provide the customized port number in the following way. The server name field would need IP\InstanceName,PortNumber.

Comment: ,If you are using any type of firewall then do not forget to include UDP port 1434 in the exception list. UDP port 1434 is a port used by the SQL Server Browser service.

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan: with net start also i am unable to start, give error: Sql browser services could not be started, no error to report

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan, on the server itself I can access the instance but when locally from my machine or any other server it gives the network specified error

Comment: KASQLDBA, please pull out the error logs in eventvwr.msc and see why it's failing.  The error will be logged.  It could be anything from permissions to something more complicated like the port being used.

Comment: @AliRazeghi: I can only see error "The SQLBrowser service encountered a critical failure." and "The SQL Server Browser service entered the stopped state." logged when starting the service failed. Cannot see anything else apart from this on event viewer.

Comment: @KASQLDBA. The SQL Server Browser service itself is disabled by default. Have you check out through 'services.msc'.

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan: Yes  checked that as well and on the listed profile, it says "Enabled"

Comment: @KASQLDBA Ok have you tried this method to get the log?  We're looking for the deeper details which should be logged somewhere. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191008.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if another process has claimed port 1434:

```
netstat -ano | findstr 1434
```

This will give you the process id of the offending process, which you can then identify:

```
tasklist | findstr /c:"<process id>"
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark Storey. I've attached the screenshot of what i can see after running the above highlighted commands. Please help me in interpreting what could be wrong here. Thnx

Comment: @KASQLDBA In the second command where I put <process id> please put the process id returned by the first command. It was "2012" when you ran it the first time.

Comment: By process id you mean the IP or 2012, sorry if i am getting something wrong here.please correct.

Comment: it is still 2012, and process comes as sqlservr.exe, as shown above in screenshot

Comment: You have a SQL Server instance using port 1434. That's why the SQL Browser service is unable to claim 1434.

Comment: in that case , should sqlserver be pointed towards 1433 or do i need to manually do anything to change the settings on browser service.

Comment: There's nothing you can change for the browser service, you need to identify the instance that's bound to 1434 and change it. Before heading down that route you can prove this is what's stopping the browser service from starting by stopping all SQL Server instances so 1434 is released, then starting the browser service. Note that if the instance is configured to start on 1434 it won't with the Browser service running.

Comment: we have two instances here, i checked that the default instance is using the port 1433 and the other named instance is using the port 3697. so is the named instance the one pointing 1434, if yes can i assign it to use 1433, not sure if both instance can be assigned to one port 1433. Please suggest, thnx!